# Method overriding in c++ : is it compile time or run time polymorphism?

Tags: c++, oop, polymorphism, runtime, compile-time

In C++, **Is function overriding run time polymorphism or compile time polymorphism?** I think it is compile time polymorphism because every information which is required to call the appropriate function is known to compiler early. As in the code below, `obj.disp();` Here compiler knows obj is the object of base class so it will immediately resolve the call to `disp()` function of base class. and same for `obj2.disp();` Here compiler knows obj2 is the object of derived class so it will call disp() function of derived class. I don't see why it is called run-time polymorphism.

Still in JAVA, people call function overriding as run time polymorphism. Please explain somebody....

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
  void disp(){
     cout<<"Super Class Function"<<endl;
  }
};

class B: public A{
public:
  void disp(){
     cout<<"Sub Class Function";
  }
};

int main() {
  //Parent class object
  A obj;
  obj.disp();
  //Child class object
  B obj2;
  obj2.disp();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is function overriding run time polymorphism or compile time polymorphism

You can only `override` virtual methods and those are there to support run-time polymorphism. A clever compiler can probably manage without `vtables` (for virtual dispatch) if all facts are known during compile time, but if they aren't, it has to be resolved in run-time.

Let a random number generator create objects from different child classes and pass them to a function accepting a base class pointer (or reference) and that function would still be able to call the object's overridden functions. This is resolved in run-time. Functions hiding base class functions or child class' overloads would not be available.

An example (without randomization):

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
public:
    void not_virtual() { std::cout << "not_virtual\n"; }
    virtual void func() = 0;

    virtual ~Foo() = 0;
};

Foo::~Foo() {}

void Foo::func() {
    std::cout << "default implementation\n";
}

class FooImpl : public Foo {
public:
    void not_virtual() {      // hiding - Foo's not_virtual()
        std::cout << "not_virtual, but in FooImpl\n";
    }
    void not_virtual(int x) { // overloading - same name, different signature
        std::cout << "not_virtual " << x << "\n";
    }
    void func() override { std::cout << "Impl\n"; }
};

void interface_user(Foo& x) { // slice away all but the Foo part of the object
                              // but
    x.func();                 // func() is in the vtable, call child class' function
    x.not_virtual();          // not in the vtable, call Foo's function
    // x.not_virtual(2);      // error: Foo doesn't have this overload
}

int main() {
    FooImpl f;

    f.func();          // calling overridden func
    f.not_virtual();   // calling function hiding the base class function
    f.not_virtual(1);  // calling overloaded func

    interface_user(f); // slicing - the function takes a Foo&
}
```

Output:

```
Impl
not_virtual, but in FooImpl
not_virtual 1
Impl
not_virtual
```

Answer (score 1):

Only virtual function calls are resolved at runtime. If the functions are non-virtual, as in your example, the calls are resolved at compile time.

Looking at the unoptimized assembly (generated by gcc 9.2 with -O0), the main function gets compiled to:

```
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        lea     rax, [rbp-1]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    _ZN1A4dispEv
        lea     rax, [rbp-2]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    _ZN1B4dispEv
        mov     eax, 0
        leave
        ret
```

The weird names `_ZN1A4dispEv` and `_ZN1B4dispEv` are the result of name mangling: in cases like this, the compiler creates unique names for functions (keep in mind that in assembly there is no oop). The actual mangling is compiler defined, but you can notice the name of the class (`A` and `B`, respectively) and the name of the function `disp`.

If `disp` were declared as `virtual` in `A`, then `main` would look like:

```
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
->      mov     eax, OFFSET FLAT:vtable for A+16
->      mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rax
        lea     rax, [rbp-8]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    A::disp()
->      mov     eax, OFFSET FLAT:vtable for B+16
->      mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-16], rax
        lea     rax, [rbp-16]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    B::disp()
        mov     eax, 0
        leave
        ret
```

The lines marked with `->` are vtable queries, used to resolve the function call at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

yes, function overriding with objects of base and derived classes are come in compile time polymorphism.
To Acheive run time poly morphism we should use virtual or pure virtual functions. And it shoud be accessed by using a pointer or reference of base class.`enter code here`

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class Base {
public:
  virtual void fun() = 0; //pure virtual function
};
class Derived: public Base {
public:
    void fun() {
      cout << "Derived:fun"<<endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
   Base *ptr = new Derived();
   ptr->fun();//here the address of fun() knows only at run time.
}
```